# jQuery table header plugin misbehaves sometimes

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am at my wit's end attempting to troubleshoot a bug and hope someone can provide an idea what to do next.  This is the situation.

I am programming a dynamic site in PHP using CodeIgniter as a framework.  I have modified the appearance of a page heavily and incorporated some jQuery features. As part of my work-flow a static version of the page was created so that I can parse it, rather than wrestle with it if PHP and mark-up are both present.  I have a fully validated, error-free page in static html that works perfectly.

**However, when I modify the PHP page, a jQuery plugin for keeping a table header in a static position does not work.**  By all appearances, the page should work.

Here is my checklist I have gone through about a dozen times:

- jQuery is being called once.  Part of my workflow for a static version streamlines code that may come from using the work of others and different versions of jQuery that might have been available when a plug-in was created.
- jQuery utilized by the non-working plug-in is recent and is the one I have elected to run for all other jQuery code I have added.  Some of the other plugins called on older versions and they are running perfectly with the updated jQuery source.
- jQuery is being called from the google API and is loading for other functions and events are working in the static and PHP versions of the file.
- Checked the structure, classes and id's of `div`'s to ensure they meet the requirements of the plug-ins being used.
- Checked the paths on the css and js files to make sure they load. The `baseurl()` function of CodeIgniter ensures these are always absolute.
- I am using includes on the PHP version to call js and css files common to all views I have created.  Troubleshooted these by going without includes, opting to hard code them in directly.  No joy.
- Tailed the PHP `error.log` for my development stack.  Both the static and PHP versions render no errors or warnings.  The `php.ini` file for this development stack is set to report all errors and warnings.
- The virtual host definition for this site is set-up to not permit any caching of css, js, html or php files.  I have even gone so far as to modify small tidbits (comments, re-position some lines, etc.) of code to ensure it is always the most recent source code loaded in the browser.  The changes are appearing when I view source or look at the code in a browser's developer tools.

Thank you for taking the time to read this.  If you have any ideas or suggestions, I would love to read them.

Comment: And can we assume you already checked the browser’s error console for any errors?

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for suggesting the console.  I re-examined it using the php version and it yielded errors that running the same syntax on the static html version did not.  I am currently working on resolving these before trying to fix the php version.